# Decoding MIME/SMIME Messages in Biztalk

Tags: encryption, biztalk

I am developing a sample Encryption/Decryption solution in biztalk. for that purpose I created Test certificate by using Testcert utility. Then I successfully encrypted a message through MIME/SMIME encoder using test certificate. My problem is when I try to decrypt the previously encrypted file I get following error message:

There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "EncryptionDecryption.ReceivePipeline1, EncryptionDecryption, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de95fc107454e1ca" Source: "MIME/SMIME decoder" Receive Port: "ReceivePort4" URI: "C:\BIZTalkProjects\EncryptionDecryption\DecIN*.xml" Reason: There was an authentication failure. "Failed to decode the S/MIME message. The S/MIME message may not be valid.

What could be the reason? please help me. I am using biztalk server 2010.

Regards,
Shabbir

Comment: I asked to close this question because there is too little information for us to reproduce what is going on.

Comment: Obviously, I can't answer now, but the starting point to investigate would be whether you could decrypt the messages yourself using the same certificate. And whether your messages are well-formed Mime messages. And whether you have Cumulative Update 2 installed which fixes a bug in this area of BizTalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the procedures to write and read out the data? Decoding usually happens before the content is decrypted. Make sure that the file is complete and fully available in memory before the decrypt methods are called.

Comment: thanks for reply, Sorry I didn't get your point. I am just using simple xml to encrypt and decrypt.